# UPDATED: Localization stopped working in existing iPad app

Tags: ios7, localization, xcode5

I have localized my iPad app to 9 languages, all of which were working until I made some modifications *manually* to both the Mainstoryboard.strings and Localizable.strings files.  Now **nothing** will localize in the simulator or on my iPad.

This might have happened when I changed from a iOS 6.1 build to the 7.0 build ( say this because I tried using my previous version of the app, and it localizes fine!)... that's the only thing I can think of.  However, when I changed it back to 6.1, all of the changes I made for 7.0's code deprecations no longer work, so I had to go back to 7.0

[image]

I have been looking for the past 4 hours at everything involved in the project; I cleaned the app several times, I made sure the folders (in Finder) are clean and correct, no files are missing from the app and the localizable and Mainstoryboard strings files have been checked for accuracy.  I did an Analyze and it's clean.

I don't know what to do next... I'm at a standstill and can't submit the modified app to the App Store until I get this fixed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be an issue with the font(s) you're using? Fonts for  Latin alphabets don't necessarily support Vietnamese. Futura, for instance, doesn't include the full range of diacritical marks. In my experience, using a font that doesn't support Vietnamese results in the app falling back to the system font for displaying the unsupported characters (like ế) but perhaps the app just fails to display the strings at all in this case.

Comment: It could, because Korean, Chinese and Japanese don't use Latin characters at all, so they're either fully supported by the specified font or fall back to the system font, as they do for Futura. Vietnamese is a special case, since it uses a sort of "extended" Latin alphabet. Can you replace the contents of the Vietnamese MainStoryboard.strings with with one of the working languages and see if it works? If replacing the content works, then it must be an encoding or font issue with the characters; if it doesn't work then the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: See **UPDATE** to question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:  the strings files were NOT added to **Copy Bundle Resources**.  I added them and now all languages are localized.